# How to obtain one-step ahead forecast in Python based on GARCH?

Tags: volatility, programming, time-series, garch, forecasting

I am trying to produce one-step ahead forecast using GARCH in Python using a fixed windows method. I ultimately want to put the code below in a for loop, but this code snippet does not perform as I expect.

```
egarch = arch_model(train_data, mean='zero', lags=0, vol='EGARCH', p=1, o=1, q=1, dist='normal')
egarch_fit = egarch.fit();
prediction = egarch_fit.forecast(horizon=1);
prediction.variance
```

I expected the final line to print a numeric value, the one step ahead prediction based on train_data. However, the output I get is a dataframe with many NaN values and the prediction. How do I obtain the numerical forecasts? And how come the length of the returned dataframe is equal to the original sample size and not the size of train_data?

I read the reference (https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate/forecasting.html#arch.univariate.base.ARCHModelForecast) and it makes me believe that a for loop is not necessary to get one-step ahead forecasts based on a fixed window. However, I do not know how to obtain such a result. Furthermore, the code in the reference returns a dataframe, but I prefer a simple array of predictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given mu for mean,and var for variance, next step forecast is:

```
mu=prediction.mean.iloc[-1,0]
var=prediction.variance.iloc[-1,0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I do believe there exists a more efficient method without for loop, but this definitely works.

Comment: there's no for loop.  "mu for mean" means "mu variable" is used for predicting the mean of the process, not a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

#### For anybody still wondering how to produce forecasts using the `arch` package:

Kevin Sheppard, the author of the `arch` package, has "recently" uploaded  **[an extensive applied documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/arch/downloads/pdf/latest/)** on how to use different features/methods provided in the package. This includes different forecasting methods (*see chapter 1.3 in his documentation*), which can be extended to alternative models. To reiterate from the documentation, **you can do a fixed window forecast as follows** (*pp. 29 -30*):

> Fixed-windows forecasting uses data up to a specified date to generate all forecasts after that date. This can be
> implemented by passing the entire data in when initializing the model and then using `last_obs` when calling `fit`.
> `forecast()` will, by default, produce forecasts after this final date.
>
> ```
> res = am.fit(last_obs="2011-1-1", update_freq=5)
> forecasts = res.forecast(horizon=5, reindex=False)
> ```

or **a rolling window forecast** (*pp. 30 - 31*):

> Rolling window forecasts use a fixed sample length and then produce one-step from the final observation. These can
> be implemented using first_obs and last_obs.
>
> ```
> index = returns.index
> start_loc = 0
> end_loc = np.where(index >= "2010-1-1")[0].min()
> forecasts = {}
> for i in range(20):
>    sys.stdout.write(".")
>    sys.stdout.flush()
>    res = am.fit(first_obs=i, last_obs=i + end_loc, disp="off")
>    temp = res.forecast(horizon=3, reindex=False).variance
>    fcast = temp.iloc[0]
>    forecasts[fcast.name] = fcast
> ```

**Quick summary of internal parameters**:

- `last_obs` is the last included observation in your fixed window (or to estimate your model).
- `update_freq` the frequency at which the model refits the new data and produces forecasts.
- `horizon` returns the number of analytical forecasts at each time-period.
- `reindex = False` returns the smallest DataFrame that contains all of the results. If `True`, then returns the forecast results as the same shape of data used to fit the model.  This might have been OP's problem regarding the shape of the output.
- `disp` displays optimization results.
- `first_obs` is the first observation to use when estimating the model.

---

**For the above snippets to work, here is the preliminary code** (*p. 27*):

````
import datetime as dt
import sys
import arch.data.sp500
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from arch import arch_model

data = arch.data.sp500.load()

market = data["Adj Close"]
returns = 100 * market.pct_change().dropna()

am = arch_model(returns, vol="Garch", p=1, o=0, q=1, dist="Normal")
```
````